uwsgi and systemd socket activation
uwsgi is supposed to support systemd's socket activation according to the docs, but I cannot get it to work. My config looks like this:
# /etc/systemd/system/uwsgi-django.socket
[Unit]
Description=Socket for uWSGI for Django
PartOf=uwsgi-django.service

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/uwsgi-django/djangoproject3.socket
SocketUser=www-data
SocketGroup=www-data
SocketMode=0660

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target

# /etc/systemd/system/uwsgi-django.service
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI for Django
After=syslog.target
Requires=uwsgi-django.socket

[Service]
ExecStart=/var/www/virtualdjango/bin/uwsgi --master --emperor /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled
Restart=always
User=www-data
Group=www-data
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all
RuntimeDirectory=uwsgi
StandardInput=socket

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

# /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/djangoproject3.ini
[uwsgi]
# socket = /run/uwsgi-django/djangoproject3.socket 
chdir = /var/www/djangoproject3/ 
module = djangoproject3.wsgi 
processes = 10 
# chmod-socket    = 660 
vacuum = true 

With the socket and chmod-socket parameters commented out in the uwsgi config file, uwsgi does not inherit the socket created by systemd, but complains about a missing option ("The -s/--socket option is missing and stdin is not a socket.") and does not spawn the vassal processes. But the uwsgi docs are quite clear about the socket option being superfluous when using systemd socket activation. As soon as I remove the comments in djangoproject3.ini and restart the service unit, uwsgi obviously takes charge of the socket, and everything works.
What am I missing here?
